How does salt water conduct current?
Think of a simple system - a battery is connected to two Pt electrodes that are both submerged in a glass of pure water with some NaCl.
You always hear people say that in the conductors (leads/Pt electrodes) the charge carrier is the electron, and the charge carriers in the solution are the ions.
So as soon as you connect your battery to the wires, electrons start moving in the wires and ions start shutteling through the solutions to the appropriately charged Pt electrode.
But what happens at the surface of the electrode?
Assuming the voltage isn't high enough to reduce and plate Na on the Pt, and to oxidize the Cl to start evolving Cl2 gas - is this system going to act like a capacitor?
What do we mean when we say that salt water is conductive?

In such a case, the current would be short-lived. Capacitors of electrode surfaces would charge up. The external potential difference would cause the ongoing ion displacement, which in the turn would create the coulombic potential counter-gradient, so the current would gradually cease. The final ion displacement would be very small, as even small ones cause strong coulombic net force.
BTW, $\ce{Na/Na+}$ redox system has too low reduction potential for metallic sodium to be formed. Water is reduced to $\ce{H2}$ + $\ce{OH-}$ instead.
There is more sense in talking electrolyte conductivity for cases of small magnitude and high enough AC frequency (ballpark values $\lt \pu{100 mV}$, $\gt \pu{1 kHz}$) where the ion displacement is cyclic and does not form countergradient.

Thanks for the answer.
Yes, you are absolutely right about the redox potential of sodium vs. water, I just wanted to use the simple example of salt water.
Also, I'm familiar with Kohlrausch's method.
Just never really thought through the case of direct current through an electrolyte without redox.
So that means there's no real meaning to talking about electrolyte conductance without redox under DC, does it?
In that case, can water-based electrolytes be used as dielectric media in capacitors? since they are practically insulators when in DC regime...

Without insulation layers, there would little use for capacitors of such low $U_\text{max}$ // Otherwise, see wikipedia.org - Electrolytic capacitor // It is not that electrolytes have no AC conductivity. It is just not well defined and measureable, due transient phenomena.
